# Read and write details in Plist

Tags: iphone, ios, plist

i created a plist names infoD.plist in documnet directory of the xcode like his[image] image

i just want to chnage the NO to YES in some cases in my code.I neeed like this

```
infoD plist objectAtIndex:10 to YES if purchased.if the user purchased something ,i need to chnage the iteam10 value to YES. how to do this.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use NSMutableDictionary to grab plist contents of ur plist

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:<filepath>];

[dict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"item 10"];
[dict writeToFile:<filepath> atomically:YES];
```

Comment: NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"infoD" ofType: @"plist"]; 
                NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: path];
            [dict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"item 10"];
                [dict writeToFile:path atomically:YES];  ///// is this corect

Comment: no. u are using incorrect path. You need to provide the path where you have kept in the documents directory. if you provide path from bundle,  you will not be able to write it back as bundle is readonly. you have mentioned you have this file in ur documents directory - "i created a plist names infoD.plist in documnet directory"

Comment: ohhh,i put the infoD.plist in the supporting folder

Comment: if you want to read/write any data to this plist, you must copy it to the documents directory first where you have r/w rights. NSBundle's resources are readonly so you cannot save any changes to ur plist file to resources in Application's bundle. Best of luck!!